# How to switch off message templates in V11?

Tags: front-end

In Version 10 message output was "straight forward" boxes:

[image]

However in V11 messages are now template boxes:

[image]

Unfortunately this new format is playing havoc when writing logs. A solution is simply to globally set all output to OutputForm but this is undesirable. I want the output from my evaluations to be StandardForm but I would like messages to be displayed as OutputForm (in order to write readable logs).

I've tried adjusting settings in stylesheets to no avail. Unfortunately I cannot identify the option, if it exists, that will switch the templating on/off.

Does anyone have any ideas?